# Existence of a diffemorphism that maps one curve to another

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider $1 < n\in \mathbb {N} $, let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2 : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be smooth paths such that 
$$\gamma_1 (0) = \gamma_2(0) \neq \gamma_1(1) = \gamma_2(1) $$
and $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are injetive functions.

> **Question:**  Does there exist a diffeomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi (\gamma_1 ([0,1])) = \gamma_2 ([0,1]).$

Does anyone know if this result is true?

This seems true but I do not know how to prove it, can anyone help me?

Comment: Is $\Bbb R^{n>1}$ the set of functions from the interval $\{n >1\}$ into $\Bbb R$ endowed with uniform convergence on each compact subinterval?

Comment: No, it is $\mathbb {R}^n$ with $n>1$. I will change.

Comment: Are the $\gamma_i$ $C^1$?  $C^\infty$?  Merely continuous?

Comment: It cannot be true as stated because you can take $\gamma_1([0,1])$ to be a line  segment while $\gamma_2([0, 1])$ to be two disconnected line segments. I still think this will be false if you do not have $\gamma_i$ ($i=1,2$) to be differentiable with continuity. (To see why this would have to fail if the $\gamma_i$ are only continuous, take a square and each $\gamma_i$ be two of its sides.)

Comment: Smooth functions, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$: Define $$\gamma_1 (t)=\begin{cases} (e^{1/(2t-1)},0)&t\in [0,1/2)\\0& t=1/2\\(0,e^{1/(1-2t)})&t\in (1/2,1]\end{cases}$$

This is a $C^\infty$ injective mapping that that traces out the line segment $[(1/e,0),(0,0)]$ followed by the segment $[(0,0),(0,1/e)].$

Note that $\gamma_1$ makes a right angle turn at $(0,0).$ There is no diffeomorphism that can turn $\gamma_1$ into the usual straight line segment $\gamma_2$ from $(1/e,0)$ to $(0,1/e).$